# How can i add a horizontal line to this bar chart to show recommended levels of data?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have this bar chart (code below) and i with to add a horizontal line across all bars at 10 on the Y axis to show recomended levels s PM2.5. Would anyone know how to change the code to do this?
Data;

```
head(air_pollution_bar)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Continent                mn
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 Africa                 41.1
2 Americas               19.5
3 Eastern Mediterranean  47.0
4 Europe                 15.6
5 South-East Asia        37.7
6 Western Pacific        16.4
```

Code;

```
 ggplot(life_bar, aes(x = reorder(Continent, -mn), y = mn, fill = 
   Continent)) + 
   geom_col() +
   ylab('Life Expectancy') +
   xlab('Continent') +
   theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Comment: Try `geom_hline(yintercept = 10)`

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway i can add a label to this line? Either on the line or to the side of the plot?

Comment: Sure, e.g. `annotate(geom = "text", y = 10, x = -Inf, hjust = -.1, vjust = -.1, label = "My Label")` will put an annotation on top of the line.